Poor network bandwidth on a point to point connection between 2 linux machines with Mellanox ConnectX-6 cards
For both machines:

Ubuntu 20.04
Mellanox MT28908 ConnectX-6 cards in ethernet mode
Kernel module: mlx5_core (from MLNX_OFED_LINUX-24.04-0.6.6.0-ubuntu20.04-x86_64)

The ConnectX-6 cards are directly connected to each other using an Nvidia DAC using RFC1918 addresses; i.e. a little 2-node network. The machines are server grade rackmount systems, with one having an Intel Xeon Gold 5318Y CPU, and the other 2 x Intel Xeon Platinum 8358 CPUs. These cards are supposed to provide 100Gb/s connectivity.  However
root@zakynthos:~# iperf3 -c 192.168.101.1
Connecting to host 192.168.101.1, port 5201
[  5] local 192.168.101.2 port 45974 connected to 192.168.101.1 port 5201
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr  Cwnd
[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec  3.17 GBytes  27.2 Gbits/sec  227    912 KBytes       
[  5]   1.00-2.00   sec  2.58 GBytes  22.1 Gbits/sec  1382    755 KBytes       
[  5]   2.00-3.00   sec  2.36 GBytes  20.3 Gbits/sec  2459   1.08 MBytes       
[  5]   3.00-4.00   sec  3.07 GBytes  26.4 Gbits/sec  3433    723 KBytes       
[  5]   4.00-5.00   sec  3.36 GBytes  28.9 Gbits/sec  3004   1.05 MBytes       
[  5]   5.00-6.00   sec  2.83 GBytes  24.3 Gbits/sec  1692    942 KBytes       
[  5]   6.00-7.00   sec  2.47 GBytes  21.2 Gbits/sec  1819   1022 KBytes       
[  5]   7.00-8.00   sec  3.03 GBytes  26.0 Gbits/sec  1578    841 KBytes       
[  5]   8.00-9.00   sec  3.37 GBytes  28.9 Gbits/sec  1920   1024 KBytes       
[  5]   9.00-10.00  sec  2.91 GBytes  25.0 Gbits/sec  1239   1.06 MBytes       
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec  29.1 GBytes  25.0 Gbits/sec  18753             sender
[  5]   0.00-10.04  sec  29.1 GBytes  24.9 Gbits/sec                  receiver

I'm used to seeing iperf3 deliver around 90% of the rated bandwidth for a card, so to me this looks terrible and unacceptable. Anyone have any insights as to why I'm not seeing at least 80-90Gb/s performance here?

Whats your ethernet configuration look like? Jumbo frames? My first thought is that the packets/second might be hitting some limit before the bandwidth is. I would be looking first to see what else is going on at the time (CPU usage, mostly). The only other thing is on your machine with dual sockets - I have seen once or twice crappy performance due to the PCIe lanes being connected to one CPU, but the other CPU being the one thats doing the heavy lifting.

The only other thing I can think of is that PCIe 4.0 speeds are 16Gbps/lane, and you are roughly around the 2x PCIe 4.0 lane speed - so maybe something hasn't negotiated properly, there wasn't enough free lanes on a CPU, or one of the motherboards has only wired up to x2 for one of the slots (even if the slot is physically longer)

Continuing to think out loud: 2x  PCIe 4.0 is equivalent to 4x PCIe 3.0, and not all PCIe slots are equal in many servers (not knowing which brand/model you've got there I'm speculating), so maybe one of the cards is installed in a PCIe 3.0 slot?

@MarkHenderson Hi Mark, thanks for the helpful comments. When I run lscpi -vv on both the server and the client I get LnkSta: Speed 16GT/s (ok), Width x16 (ok). This tell me that the cards are in PCIe 4 x16 slots, so the bandwidth cap of the bus would be 16GT/s x 16 = 256Gb/s.  So I don't think it's that.  The MTU on both cards is 1500, and I'm informed that this is autonegotiated by the device and it's typically not a good idea to change this; but in any case not Jumbo frames (9000 MTU).

The problem was the version of iperf3 that ships with Ubuntu 20.04 is incapable of handling bandwidths greater than around 25Gb/s. I downloaded and compiled the newest version of iperf3 (which supports running parallel streams), and running 16 parallel client streams:
/opt/iperf-3.17.1/bin/iperf3 -c 10.119.8.9 -P 16

I was able to get around 98-99Gb/s, which is close enough to the theoretical max for the card.

server grade rackmount systems - what are those systems and specifically which slot have you plugged the NIC in?
The MT28908 ConnectX-6 supports PCIe 4.0 x16 with a theoretical bandwidth of up to 252 Gbit/s - sufficient for 2x 100 GbE. However, if that slot only supports e.g. PCIe 3.0 x4 electrically ("x16 @ x4"), then bandwidth drops to 31 Gbit/s with pretty much the result you're seeing.
Another possibility is a poor memory setup with just a single channel (admittedly unlikely).
Check your server specs.
